# load arrays from files at ProgramLaunch event with C#

Tags: c#, file-upload

Right now I create following arrays (on Button_click event):

```
string[,] Butt = new string[2, 3] { 
                 { "120", "200", "#ffc90e" },
                 { "380", "200", "#22b14c" } 
               };

int[,] arrat = new int[,] {
                    { 199, 199 },
                   { 257, 189 },
                   { 407, 185 },
                   { 521, 196 },
                   { 608, 232 },
                   { 620, 300 },
                   { 509, 338 },
                   { 386, 344 },
                   { 288, 347 }
                  };
```

I want to optimize my code so I don't have to crete new arrays each time. Better solution will be - to load arrays from file on program launch

lets say I have a CSV file with following content:

```
199, 199

257, 189

407, 185

521, 196
```

**how do I load everything into an array: "int[,] array = new int[,]" ??**

Comment: How is that optimizing? It won't be faster

Comment: Not only it won't be faster - it`ll be slower!

Comment: File is **muuuch** slower than any in-memory operation. Forget that.

Comment: I guess with _optimize_ he means it'll be more easy to maintain!

Comment: I will load them only once, at start, not onButtonClick event!~This will allow me to MODIFY them as I wish without editing my code ;)

Comment: If you want speed, declare the buttons literally on controls. Why load them at runtime at all.

Comment: If you don't want to compile your code, why use .Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put some error checking but you may start from:

```
private static string[,] Parse(string path, int columnCount, char columnSeparator = ',')
{
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

 string[,] result = new string[lines.Length, columnCount];
 for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < lines.Length; ++rowIndex)
 {
  string[] columns = lines[rowIndex].Split(new char[] { columnSeparator }, columnCount);

  for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columns.Length; ++columnIndex)
   result[rowIndex, columnIndex] = columns[columnIndex];
 }

 return result;
}
```

Helper method for conversion (instead you may want to embed in the `Parse()` method):

```
private int[,] ConvertToInt(string[,] matrix)
{
 int[,] result = new int[matrix.GetLength(0), matrix.GetLength(1)];
 for (int i = 0; i < result.GetLength(0); ++i)
 {
  for (int j = 0; j < result.GetLength(1); ++j)
  {
   int value = 0;
   if (Int32.TryParse(matrix[i, j], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value))
    result[i, j] = value;
  }
 }

 return result;
}
```

(I'm not using LINQ 'cause I guess you should put **a lot** of error checking inside that methods to validate input data).

Answer (score 1):

```
int[][] array = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("myFilePath")
      .Select(line => line.Split(',')
      .Select(entry => Convert.ToInt32(entry.Trim()))
      .ToArray())
      .ToArray();
```

Comment: Great solution! Not only it works great, but it also takes 1 line of code ;) Although, I'd prefer Multidimensional Array[,] instead of Jagged Array[][].. but anyway, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define those arrays as static members in a class. In this way, they won't be regenerated each time you create new instances of that object.

To load them from file use StreamReader class's ReadToEnd method and then split('\r\n') to get the lines and split(',') for the numbers array